# measure theory and convergence

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

1) Let $\Omega=[0,1]$, $F = B([0,1])$, $P$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ ($P([a,b])=b-a$).
Set
$$A_n^i:=\left[{\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}}\right]$$
and
$$X_n^i(\omega):=\chi_{A_n^i}(\omega)$$

Consider the sequences 
$$\{X_1^1,X_2^1,X_2^2,X_3^1,X_3^2,X_3^3\},\quad n \geq 1,\,i=1,2,\dots,n$$

Show that this sequence converges to the zero r.v. both in probability and in $L^2(\Omega, F, P)$, but does not converge at any point $\omega \in [0,1]$.

2) Let the probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ be as above. Find a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ that converges to the zero random variable a.s. but such that $E|X_n|^p \rightarrow \infty$ for every $0 < p < \infty$.